# How to use all the dynamic input recursively with a dynamic function in python?

Tags: python, function, nested

I will explain the example since its easer to describe that way:

Say we have an undetermined (X) number of variables that can be either lists or strings.

For the example, X=3, and we have:

```
Var1=list("a","b")
Var2=list("c","d")
Var3="e"
```

And all of those are together in a list:
ListOfVariables=[Var1,Var2,Var3]

Then we have a function (we dont know this function in advance, but it uses the same number X of variables that we have) that runs on those variables.

```
def Function(Var1,Var2,Var3)
    print Var1
    print Var2
    print Var3
```

The objective here is to make the Function run with all the input variables, and in case one of those is a list, it must do the Function for each item of the list. So the wanted result would be to call Function for all of them, like this:

```
Function(a,c,e)
Function(a,d,e)
Function(b,c,e)
Function(b,d,e)
```

So far, Im using a helper function that will identify Var1,Var2, and Var3, but my brain doesnt have so much recursion predictability as to be able to define this HelperFunction such as:

```
def HelperFunction():
    for item in ListOfVariables:
        if type(item).__name__=='list':
            #This one will be done as a "for", so all the items in this list are executed as input (Var1 and Var2 in the example)
        else:
            #This item doesnt need to be included in a for, just execute once (Var3 in the example)
```

I know it can be done with python, but I cant program in my mind the function that I need, its one degree of complexity more than my "brain emulator" can emulate python =(

Thank you very much for your help.

---

### EDIT AFTER ANSWERS:

Thank you very much for the answers, but Im not sure if the proposed solution solves the problem.
If we run:

```
helper_function(ListOfVariables)
```

Then helper_function should call the function "Function" 4 times, like this:

```
Function(a,c,e)
Function(a,d,e)
Function(b,c,e)
Function(b,d,e)
```

The intention is to use all the variables in the input, BUT in their corresponding place within the Function needs.
More specifically, the logic process for the helper_function(ListOfVariables) is:

Var1 is a list, therefore, I will have to loop through its contains and run Function() with those, but those will ONLY be the first argument of the function!

Var2 is a list, therefore, I will also loop, with the items being ONLY the second argument of the Function()

Var3 is a single item, therefore, for the other two loops, this value will be assigned constant.

That is how we get the desired:

```
Function(a,c,e)
Function(a,d,e)
Function(b,c,e)
Function(b,d,e)
```

Thank you very much, I just cant figure this out myself!

Comment: so.. you.. want it to take the variables and run `Function` on every existing combination between the three given arguments. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and I believe that is what John spong answer does. Actually, tested and working now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then to generalize the problem further: you want to iterate the function on the product of all the elements within the arguments; non-list arguments should be treated as lists that contain only themselves. Using the `itertools` module, and treating this as an iterative rather than recursive process simplifies things:

```
import itertools

def combine(*args):
    lists = [arg if isinstance(arg, list) else [arg] for arg in args]
    for a, b, c in itertools.product(*lists):
        Function(a, b, c)

Var1=["a","b"]
Var2=["c","d"]
Var3="e"

combine(Var1, Var2, Var3)
```

If you need to handle lists-of-lists, then you need a recursive process.

Answer (score 1):

Is this broadly what you're looking for?

```
def helper_function(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, basestring):
            do_something(item)
        else:
            helper_function(item)
```

If the item in the list is a string, then you run your function against it. If it isn't then you just call the helper function again on the item, since it accepts any arbitrary list containing strings.

Comment: I think you would be better checking for a list or tuple for the recursion and do the do_something in the else ... if an item in the list is an int(for example) this will blow up  +1 though since this will work if all he has is strings and lists

Comment: Updated answer, this is close, but in my tests doesnt run as expected, more details on edited questions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't know how many arguments to expect and you wish to run a function on them nevertheless. If so, you want to use the `*` to define an unknown amount of args that will be treated as a list. Then it's simply a conditions, like so:

```
def some_name(*args):
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, list):
            some_name(*arg)
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            print arg
```

Is that it?

Comment: Answer updated, the number of arguments is known, but they might be either lists or single argumens. The objective is to make the function use all of them recursively, as detailed in the answer edit. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
def recurse_me(my_list):
    if not isinstance(my_list,(list,tuple)):
        print "Unexpected Arg! not a list!!:",my_list
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item,(list,tuple)):
            print "Recursive Call! recurse_me(%s)"%item
            recurse_me(item)
         else:
            print "Normal:",item
```

not sure if this is what you wanted but I think so

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the arguments directly?

```
def func(*vars):
  for var in vars:
    dostuff_with_var(var)
```

In `dostuff_with_var` you can check the type and act accordingly.